# go-gnuplot で `could not find path to 'gnuplot'` エラーが発生する

Tags: go

Debina上で、golang（version 1.6.2）でコードを書いております。
github.comの中にあるlibraryを使用したいのですが、
エラーが発生しており、修正の方法がわからず困っています。
どなたかにご教授をいただきたく、ここで質問させていただいています。

[go-gnuplot](https://github.com/sbinet/go-gnuplot)というlibraryをインストールしたいです。

```
go get github.com/sbinet/go-gnuplot
```

このlibraryが、「.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.2/global/src/github.com/sbinet/go-gnuplot」にインストールしたことは確認できました。
そこで、上記のurlに記載されているサンプルコード(仮にtest.gognuplot.goとします)をコピペして、

```
go run test.gognuplot.go
```

で起動させたところ、以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
** could not find path to 'gnuplot':
exec: "gnuplot": executable file not found in $PATH
panic: could not find 'gnuplot'

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x4dc060, 0xc82000a330)
        /home/xxx/.gvm/gos/go1.6.2/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
github.com/sbinet/go-gnuplot.init.1()
        /home/xxx/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.2/global/src/github.com/sbinet/go-gnuplot/gnuplot.go:32 +0x1aa
github.com/sbinet/go-gnuplot.init()
        /home/xxx/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.2/global/src/github.com/sbinet/go-gnuplot/gnuplot.go:446 +0x54
main.init()
        /home/xxx/programs/go/test.gognuplot.go:26 +0x3b
exit status 2
```

$PATHかなとおもいましたので、`echo $PATH`でみましたところ、
`/home/xxx/bin:/home/xxx/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.2/global/bin:/home/xxx/.gvm/gos/go1.6.2/bin:/home/xxx/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.2/global/overlay/bin:/home/xxx/.gvm/bin:/home/xxx/.gvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`
でした。

ちなみに$GOPATHは、
`/home/xxx/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.6.2/global`
です。

PATHが通っていないのがエラーだと思いますが、
このlibraryないにはbinがないので、どこを修正してよいのかわかりません。

エラーの修正方法がわからず困っています。
ご教授をお願いします。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `exec: "gnuplot": executable file not found in $PATH` となっていますので、`gnuplot` コマンドがインストールされていなのではないかと思います。別途、gnuplot パッケージをインストールすると良いかと(例えば `apt-get install gnuplot`)。

Comment: ありがとうございました。てっきりgnuplotがgo-gnuplotのことだと勘違いしておりました。ご指摘された通り、gnuplot自体がインストールされていませんでしたので、それをインストールしたら解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

(コメント転記)

`exec: "gnuplot": executable file not found in $PATH` となっていますので、 `gnuplot` コマンドがインストールされていなのではないかと思います。別途、 `gnuplot` パッケージをインストールすると良いかと思います
(例えば `apt-get install gnuplot`)。